# Converse of a theorem related to elementary operations applied to a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Theorem 1 : If one of the following elementary operations is applied to a system of linear equations,
then the resulting system is equivalent to the original system.

1. Interchange two equations.
2. Multiply an equation by a nonzero scalar.
3. Add a constant multiple of one equation to another.

Two linear systems are defined to be equivalent, if their solution sets are equal.

Consider the converse of the above theorem(framed by me):

Theorem 1c : If a linear system $P$ is equivalent to the another linear system $Q$, then $Q$ can be obtained from $P$ and vice versa, using a sequence of the following elementary operations:

1. Interchange two equations.
2. Multiply an equation by a nonzero scalar.
3. Add a constant multiple of one equation to another.

Theorem 1c seems to be correct.
How to prove the converse : Theorem 1c ?
Anybody can provide hints, sequences of steps?

Comment: Strictly speaking 1c is false: the systems $\begin{array}{rcl}1x+0y&=&2\\1x+0y&=&3\end{array}$ and $\begin{array}{rcl}0x+1y&=&2\\0x+1y&=&3\end{array}$ have the same (empty) set of solutions but cannot be converted to each other.

Comment: @StinkingBishop If the converse is rewritten as "Theorem 1c : If a consistent linear system P  is equivalent to the another linear system Q", then it will be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let us State it more Precisely/Mathematically/rigorously like this :

We have a list of Consistent Equations $E_1=(E_{11},E_{12},E_{13},E_{14},\cdots,E_{1n})$ which we convert to a new list of Equations $E_2=(E_{21},E_{22},E_{23},E_{24},\cdots,E_{2n})$ with the $3$ elementary operations.
We claim that $E_1$ & $E_2$ have same Solutions-Set $S$ , in other words , $E_1 \equiv E_2$ & $E_2$ is Consistent.

Conversely : When we have 2 lists of Consistent Equations $E_1$ & $E_2$ with the same Solutions-Set $S$ , we claim that $E_1 \equiv E_2$ , in other words , $E_1$ can be converted to $E_2$ with the $3$ elementary operations.

I have added the word **"Consistent"** which is not there in OP Question. The Comment by user "Stinking Bishop" makes this necessary.

Proof of the Converse :

Let us write the Equations $E1$ with Matrices & vectors :
$A_1X=B_1$
We can convert $A_1$ (with gaussian elimination or other methods) to Diagonal Matrix , which will give the Solution $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\cdots,x_n)=(C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4,\cdots,C_n)$

Likewise we can write the Equations $E2$ with Matrices & vectors :
$A_2X=B_2$
We can convert $A_2$ (with gaussian elimination or other methods) to Diagonal Matrix , which will give the Solution $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\cdots,x_n)=(C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4,\cdots,C_n)$ , which we know is Exactly Same.

This Diagonal Case is Equivalent to $E_1$ & $E_2$ , hence these two must be Equivalent too.

Comment: You cannot _always_ convert those systems to a _diagonal_ matrix, because nowhere in the problem it says that the number of equation is equal to the number of variables - or that the equations are independent, for that matter. All you can do is convert them to some weaker canonical form, e.g. [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).